# Make menu follow current page

Tags: mmenu

```
Page A
  Page A 1
  Page A 2
Page B
Page C
```

I need the mMenu to follow the current page so if I enter Page A 2, I want the menu to open that submenu automatically.

Checked the addons but couldnt fint anything to achive this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a common problem finding this configuration setting in Mmenu, but here is how you initialize Mmenu to default to the current page: Use the `selected` configuration setting within `classNames`.

```
$("#menu").mmenu({
    //Options        
    "offCanvas": {
        "zposition": "front" //Just an example option
    }
}, {
    //Configuration
    classNames: {
        selected: "current-page" //Change this class to match the default li you want
    }
});
```